# How does Android manage their Animations not to stutter?

Tags: android, animation, view

Android's API 15 Animation class contain this:

```
public boolean getTransformation(long currentTime, Transformation outTransformation) {
      ... code ...
}
```

The method calculate the delta time and send it to an Interpolator which in turn based on the time the Animation has run, returns a value which in turn is applied to the Transformation.

When I build my own custom Views I use the post(Runnable) method and then call my logic update, invalidate and then post(Runnable) again if some condition is not met. The logic call takes 1 ms, the overriden onDraw(Canvas) also takes 1 ms. What is bugging me is the invalidate() call which often make my delta time go up to values above 40 (40 ms is 25 frames per second) and it is not advisable to get values higher than that. Using delta time to calculate where to draw the next frame often stutters and is not possible. I have to not use delta time and rely on how fast the phone can update the view individually, making it go faster and slower on different phones which is not a good idea.

SurfaceViews are something I cannot work with because their structure are not in cohesion with other Views (mostly Z depth problems).

Now to my question, how did Android solve the Animations? They do not stutter and they use delta time. Somewhere they must have some magic but I cannot seem to find where. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Muggles can't see the magic :) I don't know either where exactly it is but I guess it has to do a lot with the hardware acceleration that is going on behind the scenes.